What is God's law in this article?
What is God's law mentioned in this article Asceticism Vs. Self-Denial?
Is it referring to the Ten Commandments?
I'm new to Christianity, apologies if this is a noob question 

Unless specified, “the Law” generally refers to the Mosaic Law. This would include the 10 commandments- but also all the other commandments given to the Jewish people via Moses (613 total)

Welcome to C.SE and to Christianity.  It's a fine question and the article you linked is a good article, but please include a quote mentioning God's law from the article as well as a more specific question on God's law from that quote.  In a sense, yes, the mention refers to the 10 commandments but not directly, since the main topic of the article is about following our desires lawfully and about the meaning of self denial.

It simply means God’s moral will for our lives. To love God and to love our neighbor. He is arguing that this is not asceticism when you try to do it.

Thank you for your answer :)

Welcome to the site, and for your question. For a new believer in Jesus, there can be understandable need for clarity with such articles as the one you give the link to.
It is quite a good article. Having read it all, and looking for ways to clarify the meaning of "God's law", I would set out the two Bible texts it points to. It's usually a good idea for O.Ps to do that underneath their question, to fill the readers in, and to show that they have done their homework, not expecting readers to have to wade through an entire article first. Questions should have sufficient detail to enable readers to tackle the question.
The first text raised is Titus 2:12. Here is the whole sentence:

"For the grace of God that bringeth salvation hath appeared to all
men, teaching us that, denying ungodliness and worldly lusts, we
should live soberly, righteously, and godly, in this present world."
Titus 2:11-12.K.J.V.

There is no mention of any law, but instruction is given as to how Christians are to live in the midst of ungodly people. This instruction is clear - to be godly in our living, to deny worldly lusts, to be sober, and to be living righteously. This forms a witness that enhances our verbal witness to non-Christians about how the grace of God has transformed us. As verse 10 says, this "may adorn the doctrine of God our Saviour in all things."
I would just mention a point of difference in the K.J.V.; that the grace of God brings salvation; the text does not say that "the grace of God offers salvation to all people" as in the version quoted in the article. That, however, is not the point of your question. It does show, though, the need to state in any question or answer, what translation is being used when quoting a scripture.
The next pertinent bit in that article is where law is mentioned. Bear in mind that it is about "Asceticism versus Self-Denial", and not about law. The article says:

"One who is ruled by his own selfish desires will seek to satisfy
those desires without regard for God’s laws. Self-denial requires that
our desire to obey God overrule our destructive desires to find
satisfaction outside of what God has for us."

The article rightly contrasts ungodly, selfish and lustful desires with God's holy requirements for godly living. Those can come under the heading of 'laws' in a general sense, but Paul is not making any reference in that verse to specific parts of God's law, nor to what we now call "The Ten Commandments". It is too obvious for words that people who have been transformed by the grace of God will strive to please God in every area of their living and worship. Yes, the Ten Commandments deal with that, but Jesus raised the bar far higher by saying that if we lust in our thoughts, or harbour hatred in our hearts, we have already violated those laws against adultery and murder.
When Paul writes to Timothy to "keep this commandment" (verse 14), he qualifies that by saying it is the command to "follow after righteousness, godliness, faith, love, patience, meekness, fight the good fight of faith, lay hold on eternal life, ... and profess a good profession before many witnesses." This is gleaned from verse 11 through to the end of the letter.
He goes on in 1 Timothy 6:17 to say Timothy must warn rich people in the congregation against being high-minded due to their wealth, nor to trust in their riches, as God "gives us richly all things to enjoy." That is why that verse is referred to in the article, because it's about how to enjoy life even though Christians are to deny self (in many respects) without becoming ascetics (and miserable with it.) That verse has nothing to do with old testament law.
So, the answer to the question, 'Is it referring to the Ten Commandments' is "No, not specifically or directly, for although it incorporates them in principle, it goes beyond the letter of those particular laws." The article is referring to being balanced in living a holy life, avoiding the trap of asceticism. I hope this helps you in your search for understanding principles of Christian living.

Thank you for your answer :)

It appears that the website is Baptist leaning based on the academics they have listed. Outside of Messianic and Hebrew Roots denominations most Christians believe the law was done away with, so we can exclude Mosaic/Levitical law from their definition.
But given they have consulting PhD Baptists, God's laws most likely indicates the Ten Commandments or the Royal Law: Love God with all your heart, mind and soul and your neighbor as yourself (James 2:8). Since the website is based on Faith, Work, and Economics, I assume the Book of James is part of their founding doctrine. So I would recommend reading through the Book of James.
I compiled a brief overview, there may be items missing from the list:
Chapter 1

Ask Without Doubting
Quick to Listen
Slow to Speak
Slow to Anger
Get Rid of Moral Filth
Get Rid of Every Expression of Evil
Be Doers of the Word
Care for Widows and Orphans

Chapter 2

Do Not Show Favoritism
The Royal Law
Do Not Commit Adultery
Do Not Murder
Be Merciful
Have Faith With Works to Show For It

Chapter 3

Control Your Tongue
Do Not Bless and Curse with the Same Mouth
Do Not Be Jealous
Do Not Have Selfish Ambition
Be Peaceful
Be Gentle
Be Accommodating
Be Full of Mercy and Good Deeds
Be Impartial
Be Sincere

Chapter 4

Do Not Covet
Have No Friendship with the World
Do Not Be Proud
Submit to God
Do Not Slander Your Brethren
Do Not Judge Your Brother
Do Not Boast

Chapter 5

Do Not Hoard Riches Nor Oppress With Riches
Be Patient for the Lord
Do Not Grumble or Complain
Confess Your Sins One to Another

Beside the Book of James, the article may extend God's Law to commandments such as be fruitful and multiply, or commandments in Acts like abstaining from foods dedicated to idols; sexual immortality; etc (Acts 15:29). Or Love One another as I have Loved You (John 13:34)

Just one point to query in your answer: you claim that Baptists and "most Christians believe the law was done away with". I've understood their stance to be that Christ fulfilled the law. To fulfill something does not necessarily equate with 'doing away with it', though it can lead to it being superseded with something superior. In this case, Christ's cross removed the condemnation of the law that is against all law-breakers who turn in faith to Christ. Hence my querying the claim that most Christians say the law was done away with. It was fulfilled in Christ, a subtle but important difference

Fulfill could also mean fill to the full--as in Christ added to the law. I'm unfamiliar with all the different denominations beliefs regarding law, but having a personal Messianic affiliation, I'm accustomed to seeing Christians regard "the law as done away with". I agree sacrificial laws have been superseded, but there are those who no longer hold to Lev. 23 or dietary laws or even the Sabbath which are not done away with per Messianicism. I cannot speak for every individual nor every denomination, though; the OP will have to look into Baptist doctrine to understand their view of the law.

Thank you for your answer :

God's law mentioned in the article is not the Mosaic Law or any of its components (10 commandments for example).  The law referred to is in the writer's first couple of paragraphs.
God created everything out of nothing and pronounced it good.
Further down, the author mentions this,

We believe God purposefully designed us to pursue happiness and delight. One of the areas in which we are to find this happiness and delight is in God’s creation and what we make of it.

In contrast are those who believe ascetism is good.  The author denies this as it is denying God's law that creation is good.
The author then cautions against the opposite extreme of hedonism.
In short, he says,

We are to do what God has commanded us to do, and abstain from what God has commanded us not to do.

So, God's law is rooted in creation of which we are a part.  We don't create anything, but only remold things.  For example, we cannot create wheat, but we can create bread.  We cannot create grapes, but we can create wine.

Thank you for your answer :)
